# null result variables in fragment android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I´m traying to send variables to my fragment in android with kotlin. My problem it´s when i load my fragment this values it´s null.

Im sending my data so:

```
if (jsonObject != null) {
                        val dataJson: JSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user")
                        val name = dataJson.getString("name")
                        val address = dataJson.getString("address")
                        val email = dataJson.getString("email")
                        val phone = dataJson.getString("phone")
                        val password = dataJson.getString("password")

                        val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                        // set parameter to activity
                        val b = Bundle()
                        b.putString("name", name)
                        b.putString("address", address)
                        b.putString("email", email)
                        b.putString("phone", phone)
                        b.putString("password", password)
                        intent.putExtras(b)

                        startActivity(intent)
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Logged ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
```

and in my fragment i´m capturing it:

```
val view: View =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
        var userName = arguments?.getString("name").toString()
        var userAdress = arguments?.getString("address").toString()
        var userEmail = arguments?.getString("email").toString()
        var userPhone = arguments?.getString("phone").toString()
        var password = arguments?.getString("password").toString()

        var editUserName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userName)
        var userAddresEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userAddress)
        var userEmailEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userEmailText)
        var userPhoneEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userPhone)
        var userPasswordEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userPasswordEdit)

        editUserName.setText(userName)
        userAddresEdit.setText(userAdress)
        userEmailEdit.setText(userEmail)
        userPhoneEdit.setText(userPhone)
        userPasswordEdit.setText(password)

        return view
```

But load my app, and in my EditText set null. What i´m doing wrong?.

Thanks for readme and help me

**UPDATE**

*MainActivity*

```
package com.example.citysportgym

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.example.citysportgym.EndPoint.EndPoint
import com.example.citysportgym.Fragments.ProfileFragment
import com.example.citysportgym.singleton.VolleySingleton
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var editTextEmail: EditText? = null
    private var editTextPassword: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // get btnLogin to set action
        val btnLogin = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
        editTextEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userEmail)
        editTextPassword = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userPassword)


        // ACTION BUTTON LOGIN
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener{
            login(editTextEmail!!.getText().toString(), editTextPassword!!.getText().toString())
        }
    }

    // function login
    private fun login(email:String, password:String) {
        //creating volley string request
        val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(Method.POST, EndPoint.URL,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try {
                    val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)

                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        val dataJson: JSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user")
                        val name = dataJson.getString("name")
                        val address = dataJson.getString("address")
                        val email = dataJson.getString("email")
                        val phone = dataJson.getString("phone")
                        val password = dataJson.getString("password")

                        val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                        // set parameter to activity
                        val bundle = Bundle()
                        bundle.putString("name", name)
                        bundle.putString("address", address)
                        bundle.putString("email", email)
                        bundle.putString("phone", phone)
                        bundle.putString("password", password)
                        intent.putExtras(bundle)
                        startActivity(intent)

                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Logged ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { println("volley Error .................") }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>? {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                params["action"] = "login"
                params["email"] = email
                params["password"] = password
                return params
            }
        }

        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

*ProfileActivity*

```
package com.example.citysportgym

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.nfc.Tag
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.example.citysportgym.Adapter.MyAdapter
import com.example.citysportgym.Fragments.ProfileFragment
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var tabTitle = arrayOf("Perfil", "Actividades", "Membresia")
    private var editTextName: EditText? = null
    private var editTextEmail: EditText? = null
    private var editTextphone: EditText? = null
    private var editTextPassword: EditText? = null

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
        // pager show content
        var pager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPagerProfile)
        // tabLayout it´s TabsMenu
        var tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.profileMenu)
        // Personaliced Adaprter
        pager.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, pager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabTitle[position]
        }.attach()

        val b = intent.extras
        var name = ""
        var address = ""
        var userEmail = ""
        var phone = ""
        var password = ""

        if (b != null) {
            name = b.getString("name").toString()
            address = b.getString("address").toString()
            userEmail = b.getString("email").toString()
            phone = b.getString("phone").toString()
            password = b.getString("password").toString()

            val mFragment = ProfileFragment()
            val mArgs = Bundle()
            mArgs.putString("name", name)
            mArgs.putString("address", address)
            mArgs.putString("email", userEmail)
            mArgs.putString("phone", phone)
            mArgs.putString("password", password)
            mFragment.setArguments(mArgs)
        }
    }
}
```

*ProfileFragment*

```
package com.example.citysportgym.Fragments

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.citysportgym.R

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [ProfileFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class ProfileFragment() : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var userNameConst: String? = null
    private var userAddressConst: String? = null
    private var userEmailConst: String? = null
    private var userPhoneConst: String? = null
    private var passwordConst: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var userNameConst = getArguments()?.getString(SENDING_NAME)
        var userAddressConst = getArguments()?.getString(SENDING_ADDRESS)
        var userEmailConst = getArguments()?.getString(SENDING_EMAIL)
        var userPhoneConst = getArguments()?.getString(SENDING_PHONE)
        var passwordConst = getArguments()?.getString(SENDING_PASSWORD)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)

        var editUserName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userName)
        var userAddresEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userAddress)
        var userEmailEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userEmailText)
        var userPhoneEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userPhone)
        var userPasswordEdit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userPasswordEdit)

        editUserName.setText(userNameConst.toString())
        userAddresEdit.setText(userAddressConst.toString())
        userEmailEdit.setText(userEmailConst.toString())
        userPhoneEdit.setText(userPhoneConst.toString())
        userPasswordEdit.setText(passwordConst.toString())

        var bundle: Bundle? = null
        bundle = this.arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            var name = bundle!!.getString("name")
            Log.i(TAG, "eee: " + name)
        }
        return view
    }


    companion object {
        const val SENDING_NAME = "mqttAndroidClientAddress"
        const val SENDING_ADDRESS = "mqttAndroidClientId"
        const val SENDING_EMAIL = "x"
        const val SENDING_PHONE = "x"
        const val SENDING_PASSWORD = "x"

        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(userName: String, userAddress: String, userEmail: String,
                        userPhone: String, password: String): ProfileFragment {
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString(SENDING_NAME, userName)
            args.putString(SENDING_ADDRESS , userAddress)
            args.putString(SENDING_EMAIL , userEmail)
            args.putString(SENDING_PHONE , userPhone)
            args.putString(SENDING_PASSWORD , password)
            val fragment = ProfileFragment()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }

    }
}
```

*MyAdapter*

```
package com.example.citysportgym.Adapter

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
import com.example.citysportgym.Fragments.EventFragment
import com.example.citysportgym.Fragments.MessageFragment
import com.example.citysportgym.Fragments.ProfileFragment
import com.example.citysportgym.Fragments.SportFragment

class MyAdapter (fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return ProfileFragment()
            1 -> return SportFragment()
            2 -> return EventFragment()
            else -> return MessageFragment()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to request the arguments in your `ProfileFragment` but you send them via intent into the `ProfileActivity`.

Comment: @chrjs thanks for your response. How i can to do this?

Comment: @chrjs in my profileActivity, i have my data ok my profile Activity it´s a tabMenu that have a fragment to load information

Comment: @scorpions78 I have answer but I dont know about your overall code Can I post my all code you will use that as per your requirement

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb yes, i need a example

Comment: @scorpions78 Added my answer please go through it and if you have any doubts let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Step 1- MyAdapter Class

```
class MyAdapter(manager: FragmentManager?) : FragmentPagerAdapter(
    manager!!
) {
    private val mFragmentList: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
    private val mFragmentTitleList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    fun addFrag(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position]
    }
}
```

Step 2- ProfileActivity Class

```
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        val b = intent.extras
        val tab1Fragment = ProfileFragment()
        tab1Fragment.arguments = b
        adapter.addFrag(tab1Fragment, "Perfil")
        adapter.addFrag(Tab2Fragment(), "Actividades")
        adapter.addFrag(Tab3Fragment(), "Membresia")
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
            }
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        })
    }
}
```

Step 3 - activity_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Step 4- Profile Fragment

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    var name: String? = null
    var bundle: Bundle? = null
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
        bundle = this.arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            name = bundle!!.getString("name")
        }
        val textview_first = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_first)
        textview_first.text = name
        return v
    }
}
```

Step 5 - fragment_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: @SandeshKhtalSaheb thanks for your response... I´m showing your code and i can´t show my problem. I updated my question with my code main, my activity, my fragment and my adapter... If you can show it and help me, I'd be really grateful

Comment: @scorpions78 I have updated code as per your expectations but if you will not get answers please share code with git and share link with me.

Comment: https://github.com/daviserraalonso/CitySportGym i can´t solve my problem. I don´t show my error, i don´t  know that i´m doing wrong

Comment: in this line bundle = this.arguments in ProfileFragment.kt it´s always null

Comment: @scorpions78 I have made changes with your code and shared here same like this post check once from your end and share feedback if any issues or anything else https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GKONUgWtw1Kcsb89enVmueA4GlPh9Z1q/view?usp=sharing dont miss to accept and upvote for the post.

Comment: @scorpions78 have you checked?

Comment: thanks for your help. But my problem, i think that it´s i don´t send ok my variables to fragment because to my ProfileActivity arrive ok, but in my fragment arguments it´s null